# How to get child attribute value from XML file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am having xml file with name as employeesInfo and in that the data is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmployeeDetails>
  <data>
    <empCode>DIT-GINT-0001</empCode>
    <FirstName>Dinesh</FirstName>
    <LastName>Alla</LastName>
    <Address>Guntur</Address>
  </data>
  <EmployeeDetails>
    <empCode>DIT-GINT-0002</empCode>
    <FirstName>Upendra</FirstName>
    <LastName>Maddi</LastName>
    <Address>guntur</Address>       
  </EmployeeDetails>
  <EmployeeDetails>
    <empCode>DIT-GINT-0003</empCode>
    <FirstName>Chandrkanth</FirstName>
    <LastName>Beth</LastName>
    <Address>guntur</Address>       
  </EmployeeDetails>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

And My code to get attribute{"empCode"} value is

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/employeesInfo.xml"));
XElement root = doc.Root;
string s = root.Elements("empCode").Last().ToString();
```

Requirement: I want to get empcode value of last parent element.

Example output of the above file: DIT-GINT-0003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the work -

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Temp\asd.xml");
var s = doc.Descendants("empCode").Last().Value;
```

To check whether the node exists or not -

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Temp\asd.xml");
var empCodes = doc.Descendants("empCode");
string result = string.Empty;

if(empCodes.Count() > 0)
{
     result = empCodes.Last().Value;
}
```

Comment: It works fine, I am having small doubt if suppose i am running the application for the first time then in the XML file i will not have "empcode" attribute, at that time how should i check.

Answer (score 2):

In your code sample root is `<EmployeeDetails>`. Get its childnodes and select the last one, then get the `<empCode>` of this node. I am sorry that I am writing this as an answer, I don't have enough reputation.

```
XElement lastEmployeeDetails = root.LastNode;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the last element and specific value in your case

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/employeesInfo.xml"));
XElement root = doc.Root;
string s = root.Element("EmployeeDetails").Element("empCode").LastNode.ToString();
```